# Can we have a video tutorial on SFSE that will help for newbies to get start with?

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I mean we can show a video on sign up, which will show all com unity guidelines to new users. I think this will really help people to understand the ecosystem of SFSE. As I am also new here(I joined 9 months back but was inactive last 8 months), still exploring the things. if someone guides me(like what things to be covered) i can create a video and post on YouTube.

Also we have give bonus points when user watches the entire video.

Comment: Looks like there is plural sight course available but an offcial vedio might always help. [Using Stack Overflow and Other Stack Exchange Sites](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/using-stackoverflow-stackexchange-sites) other than that there is [help](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help)

Comment: @codeyinthecloud have you tried it? It is paid but 10 days trial is available I will try and post my experience here, meanwhile you can vote for the idea if you agree with me.

Comment: +1 I haven't tried pluralsight but help is my go to place.

Comment: ok thanks! Will come back with update

Comment: While this is a noble idea, I'm not really sure if SE staffs will implement this. Also, giving bonus points for watching the entire video is IMHO not a good idea since there is no proof that the users have *really* watched the video (just like the "Informed" badge by skipping the [tour] to the bottom as quickly as possible).

Comment: Yes but we can award it only when full lenght video is watched. There is some mechanism with which we can detect minutes watched.